# Does MongoDB's aggregate engine run on the server or the client?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In designing an infrastructure I'd like to put as much processing into the application servers as opposed to my database servers - as my application servers can scale horizontally more easily.

So when thinking about how I would use MongoDB I wondered if MongoDB would utilise the computational power of the client (the mongo-client on the application server) over the computational power of the database server. I imagined this along the lines of the database server sends *all* the documents (maybe post index-lookup) to the client and the client then aggregates the data to the desired result.

I haven't found any documentation confirming if this is possible though what I have read *seems to imply* that all the aggregation is done on the database server.

So my question is *is it possible to use the mongoDB **client** to aggregate data as opposed to the mogoDB **server***

Comment: Yes it is done on the server. In a sharded environment the bulk of processing is done on the `mongos` router instance. A common deployment is to run the `mongos` instances on the same servers as the application server. So there is always that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't believe you are going to be able to do that with the current version of MongoDB. The aggregation pipeline has always run on top of the mongod process which is what is running the database software on the server. Previously there was one special case - sharded collections and databases - that split the aggregation pipeline into two pieces and ran the second half on the mongos process. If that were still true you could run mongos on your application server and run at least part of the aggregation framework on your application server.

Unfortunately that changed in version 2.6 - it now runs all on the shards and does not utilize the mongos process. From the documentation:

> Aggregation Pipeline and Sharded Collections
>
> Behavior
>
> Changed in version 2.6.
>
> When operating on a sharded collection, the aggregation pipeline is
>   split into two parts. The first pipeline runs on each shard, or if an
>   early $match can exclude shards through the use of the shard key in
>   the predicate, the pipeline runs on only the relevant shards.
>
> The second pipeline consists of the remaining pipeline stages and runs
>   on the primary shard. The primary shard merges the cursors from the
>   other shards and runs the second pipeline on these results. The
>   primary shard forwards the final results to the mongos. In previous
>   versions, the second pipeline would run on the mongos. [1]    Until all
>   shards upgrade to v2.6, the second pipeline runs on the mongos if any
>   shards are still running v2.4.

So you could run version 2.4 and use the mongos process - or keep at least one shard as version 2.4 and force the processing on to mongos.

Comment: Great. Thanks John! Think I'll simply run some of the aggregation in my application code - well I'll test it at least and see what ends up being the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, aggregation is done on the server side and to perform aggregation on mongodb client side you would need to bring all the data from the server to the client side and then process it, bringing large amount of data can be very slow, take a look at this

[aggregation in mongodb](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/06/21/aggregation-in-mongodb/)

here it says that you can do aggregation on client side, but it doesn't say how you can do that, what I think is bring all the data from the server side and store it in a variable then aggregate using javascript.

and also check this out, this may also be helpful

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/UxUvgBTHnjM